# How to draw a transparent stroke to reveal the background in CodeName one?

Tags: codenameone

I have a full screen drawing canvas with green coloured background. On the layered panel of the same form, Another drawing canvas is initiated with the user selected image as the background. Now, what I want is that the path I draw should act as an eraser so the region I draw should expose the background (in this case, green background). I don't want to set stroke colour to green. Any way the stroke colour could be transparent?

MainClass:-

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;


import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.Painter;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.io.MultipartRequest;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.URLImage;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Rectangle;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.painter.PainterChain;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class MainClass {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    SignaturePanel sp;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
        hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Button browseGallery = new Button("Browse");
        sp = new SignaturePanel();
        // hi.getLayeredPane();
        // hi.add(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(new LayeredLayout(), sp);
         System.out.println("before adding");
         hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp);
         System.out.println("after adding");

        //Image test = Image.createImage(1280, 800, 0xffff00);
        //hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,test);

        hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, browseGallery);
        browseGallery.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            Image image = URLImage.createImage((String)evt.getSource());
                            SignaturePanel sp1 = new SignaturePanel();
                            sp1.getAllStyles().setBgImage(image);
                            hi.add(hi.getLayeredPane().add(sp1));
                            //Image mutable = Image.createImage(1280, 800, 0x00ff00);
                            //hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER,mutable);
                            //image.modifyAlpha((byte) 10);

                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
            }
        });
//        hi.setGlassPane(new Painter() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              System.out.println("glasspane");
//          }
//      });


        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

SignaturePanel class (used to create the drawing canvas):-

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Font;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Stroke;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Dimension;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Rectangle;

class SignaturePanel extends Component {

    private final GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    private final Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
    private final Rectangle signatureRect = new Rectangle();
    private final Font xFont;
    private Image value;

    SignaturePanel() {
        stroke.setLineWidth(Math.max(1, Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1, true)/2));
        getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x00ff00);
        getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        xFont = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_LARGE);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to try to make this component as sensitive as possible to 
     * drag events.  If we don't do this, it requires a longer drag before the "drag" 
     * events will kick in.
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    protected int getDragRegionStatus(int x, int y) {
        return Component.DRAG_REGION_LIKELY_DRAG_XY;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param g 
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(0x666666);
        calcSignatureRect(signatureRect);
        g.drawRect(signatureRect.getX(), signatureRect.getY(), signatureRect.getWidth(), signatureRect.getHeight());
        g.drawString("X", signatureRect.getX() + Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1, true), signatureRect.getY() + signatureRect.getHeight() / 2);
        paintSignature(g);
    }

    /**
     * Paints just the signature portion of the panel.  This is is reuised to
     * also create the image of the signature.
     * @param g 
     */
    private void paintSignature(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(0x0);
        boolean oldAA = g.isAntiAliased();
        g.setAntiAliased(true);
        g.drawShape(path, stroke);
        g.setAntiAliased(oldAA);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates a rectangle (in parent component space) used for the drawn "rectangle" inside
     * which the user should draw their signature.  It tries to create a 16x9 rectangle that
     * fits inside the component with a bit of padding (3mm on each edge).
     * @param r Output variable.
     */
    private void calcSignatureRect(Rectangle r) {
        int w = getWidth() - Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(6, true);
        int h = (int)(w * 9.0 / 16.0);
        if (h > getHeight()) {
            h = getHeight() - Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(6, false);
            w = (int)(h * 16.0 / 9.0);
        }
        r.setX(getX() + (getWidth() - w) / 2);
        r.setY(getY() + (getHeight() - h)/2);
        r.setWidth(w);
        r.setHeight(h);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        Display d = Display.getInstance();
        return new Dimension(d.convertToPixels(100, true), d.convertToPixels(60, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
        path.moveTo(x(x), y(y));

        value = null;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
        path.lineTo(x(x), y(y));
        value = null;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
        value = null;
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Converts an x coordinate from screen space, to parent component space.
     * @param x
     * @return 
     */
    private int x(int x) {
        return x - getParent().getAbsoluteX();
    }

    /**
     * Converts a y coordinate from screen space to parent component space.
     * @param y
     * @return 
     */
    private int y(int y) {
        return y - getParent().getAbsoluteY();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the currently drawn signature as an image.  This only includes the 
     * areas inside the {@link #signatureRect}
     * @return 
     */
    private Image getImage() {
        calcSignatureRect(signatureRect);

        Image img = Image.createImage(signatureRect.getWidth(), signatureRect.getHeight(), 0xffffff);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.translate(-signatureRect.getX(), -signatureRect.getY());
        paintSignature(g);
        return img;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the signature as a blank path.
     */
    private void clear() {
        path.reset();
    }
}
```

Please ignore the commented out portions of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transparent stroke will just draw nothing.

You need a clear operation which is something we currently don't have. It's a feature we have internally but we didn't see a use case to expose it as an API as it includes a performance penalty.

This is a reasonable use case so feel free to [file an RFE](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) (request for enhancement) and I think we'll be able to expose a clear rect method for graphics.

At the moment your options are relatively limited, you can do pixel manipulation by drawing on a mutable image instead of directly to the screen then erase the pixels from the image by changing the RGB content of the image and creating a new image with that new content. That isn't ideal but doable.

Comment: Will that result in performance degrade (performance is a priority right now)?
Also, can we clip the image using the points in GeneralPath object with the width of the stroke? will that give the effect of an eraser? Can you provide some sort of code to go on from here? Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Drawing onto a raster is slower but probably not noticeable. The difference is the performance of the raster would be constant when you draw 1000 elements since it would just draw the one image. The vectors will slowly degrade the more elements you add. The problem of raster vs. vector is more of a conceptual one whether you want to work with pixels or vectors